# Where is the folder where the W3 Total Cache (W3TC) data is stored?

Tags: wordpress, cache

I am using W3TC and I am new to WordPress world.

How can I find the folder for cached data? Does the caching go to a particular folder? Is there way for me to track how much data is been cached from those sub-folders within the cache directory?

Answer (score 2):

W3TC stores its data in `yoursiteurl.whatever/wp-content/cache/` and from there you will have different folders based on W3TC settings.  For example, if you enable enhanced page caching, there will be a folder for `page_enhanced`

> Is there way for me to track how much data is been cached?

Not entirely sure what you are asking here. If you mean "how many megabytes is my cache" or similar, then there are lots of ways to analyze the cache folder and subfolders and get that answer.  If you are trying to track which parts of your site are cached, it should be everything you configured the plugin to cache minus any exceptions.